# Trying to put values from MS SQL Server table to a ListBox in a Form in Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to show data from a table in a ListBox in a form but haven't been successful.
The following is the code I'm using:

```
    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim stDB As String, stConn As String, stSQL As String
    Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim k As Long
    Dim cs As String
     
    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
     
    cs = "DRIVER=SQL Server;"
    cs = cs & "DATABASE=dbname;"
    cs = cs & "SERVER=."


   
     
    cnt.ConnectionString = cs
     
     
    stSQL = "SELECT * from table"
    
   
     
    With cnt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open stConn
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
    End With
     
    With rst
        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
        vaData = .GetRows
    End With
     
    cnt.Close
    
    ListBoxReqJobs.Value = vaData
    'this is the part I need help with. 
     
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnt = Nothing


End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to display the data correctly? I can't seem to format the data to show it properly with rows and there will be about 5-6 columns.

Comment: Did you do any [research](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/populate_userform_listbox_or_combobox.html)?

Comment: Any more advice I'm still not able to figure it out. I did however get the data to display but it is displayed column wise and not row wise.